# Swift - How to know when a loop has ended?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, loops

Please, forgive me as i'm **very** new to swift, and programming in general.

Believe me when I say I've tried hard to understand this, but I simply can't and would greatly appreciate any help.

say I have this function:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
  println(i)
  }
}
```

and I wanted to print to the logs "loop has finished" once this loop had completed and finished running, how would I do this? If i do:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
  println(i)
  println("loop has finished")
  }
}
```

then "loop has finished" gets printed after every time i is incremented.

I've tried reading into closures and completion handlers, but it's all going over my head at the moment and I don't really understand how i'd achieve the task above.

If there's an angel that can show me how I'd complete my above example, I'd be in your debt.

Thankyou for your patience with my currently pathetic knowledge!

Comment: Make sure you read through and understand the answer given by @ecatalano. Understanding loops and the logic behind them is very important!

Comment: @dan I don't want to sound rude here but take a programming class, it doesn't have to be swift, any programming class will do. Try to understand the basic fundamentals of programming. What you asked is so basic that you could have picked it up from any programming book. Once you understand that you can pickup any programming language easily. Core logic among all programming is the same ... if, else, for-loops, while-loops etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm actually taking a programming course right now on Udemy, and in the loops section the instructor didn't explain where to insert code that needs to be executed on completion of the loop. I tried to look around to find the information, but I guess I didn't really know how to word it. Kind people on here have explained the concept to me, and I am grateful to them for doing so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To produce the same result as what others have posted but with basic closure syntax:

```
func printFunction() {
    println("loop has finished")
}

func loopWithCompletion(closure: () -> ()) {
    for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
        println(i)
    }
    closure()
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
 loopWithCompletion(printFunction)
```

**Swift 3 Update:**

```
func printFunction() {
    print("loop has finished")
}

// New for loop syntax and naming convention
func loop(withCompletion completion: () -> Void ) {
    for i in 0 ..< 5 {
        print(i)
    }
    completion()
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
loop(withCompletion: printFunction)
```

Or

```
loop {
    print("this does the same thing")
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It was very difficult choosing between answers as they were all fantastic, but I believe this taught me the most. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the loop you tried to implement:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
    println(i)
    println("loop has finished")
  }
}
```

The reason why "loop has finished" gets printed 5 times is because it is within the for-loop.

Anything in between your brackets will be run when the loop repeats (where I entered "enter code here)

```
for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
   enter code here
 }
```

The way that loops work is, it will repeat until the condition is completed: i.e. `i<5`. Your i variable starts at 0 as you stated in  `var i=0`, and every time the loop repeats, this number increases by 1, as stated in `i++`

Once `i` is **not** less than 5 (i is equal to 5 or greater than 5), then the code following your for-loop will be run.

So if you put your println("loop has finished") right after the forloop, you know it will run when the loop is completed, like this:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
    println(i)
  }
  println("loop has finished")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
    println(i)
  }
  println("loop has finished")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you have the `println()` statement inside the loop, like this:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
  println(i)
  println("loop has finished")
  }
}
```

So it prints out "Finished" every time the loop loops.

To fix this, all you need to do is put the `println()` statement after the loop, like so:

```
func loop() {
  for var i=0; i<5; i++ {
    println(i)
  }
  println("loop has finished")
}
```

And voilà. Your app will now function properly!

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement always prints out on every loop. Thats why you should put your that statement outside the foreach loop:

```
func loop() {
  for i in 0...<5 {
    print(i)
  }
// it enters here when the loop is finished
  print("loop has finished")
}
```