# How to determine if Swift loop was interrupted

Tags: swift

In python we can use

```
for a in A:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

and have the `else` statement execute if the loop finished normally. Is there a similar construct in Swift?

Comment: Such a feature was discussed on the Swift Evolution mailing list and – as far as I can see – rejected. See https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001192.html which also shows a kind of workaround.

Comment: i think that workaround is the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a feature was discussed on the Swift Evolution mailing list and – as far as I can see – rejected. See

- [[swift-evolution] else clause for loops like that in Python](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001192.html)

which also shows a possible workaround:

```
outer: do {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        if i == 5 { break outer }
    }
    print("no break occurred")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a completion handler:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31778702/6481734

Or some use an if statement within the for loop:

```
for a in A
{
...
if (a == A[A.count - 1])
{
...
}
}
```