# Swift iOS -How to execute a completion after a loop within a loop has finished

Tags: ios, swift, loops, completionhandler

I have a loop within another loop and I want the inner loop to run a completion block once both loops have finished.

The inner loop and completion:

```
func runThenPrint(_ count: Int, completion:()->()){
    for num in 0..<(count){
        print(num)
    }
    completion()
}

func imDone(){
    print("DONE")
}
```

The outer loop with the inner and completion:

```
//outer
for num in 0..<5{
    //inner
    runThenPrint(num){imDone}
}
```

In Playgrounds I'm getting:

```
DONE
0
DONE
0
1
DONE
0
1
2
DONE
0
1
2
3
DONE
```

But I want:

```
0
1
2
3
4
DONE
```

I looked at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778352/swift-how-to-know-when-a-loop-has-ended.) but it is based on 1 loop and not a loop within a loop. I also found other posts on groups but they were based on network calls.

What's the best way to get this to run?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Show your real code please.

Comment: What is purpose of the outer loop? You would get the desired output just with `runThenPrint(5, completion: imDone)`.

Comment: @paper1111 there was an extra closing parenthesis at the end of the count variable.

Comment: @Martin R I already knew I could get it using the inner loop alone. The reason why I tried it this way is because my inner loop is going to run inside an outer loop of which I do not know how many times the outer loop will run for. I just used 0..<5 as an example but in reality it could be 10, 20, 30 etc.

Comment: What's the point of `runThenPrint` having a completion parameter? You only need such a thing if the implementation of the method is asynchronous which is not the case here.

Comment: @rmaddy it actually is for an aync method. I was trying to keep things as simple as possible. I have a firebase func that uploads a few times. I have runThenPrint inside it's completion. I noticed after the uploads are done then the fb completion runs. Say there are 7 uploads, when done it's completion starts it's loop (outer) then I have runThenPrint (inner) inside there. runThenPrint will run 7x which is fine, but I don't want "Done" to print 7x. I understand why it's happening, I just can't figure out how to stop it. So to simplify things I just posted and outer/inner loop w/completion.

Comment: Your question should be edited with slightly more code and make it clear that you are using Firebase and that you have async processing going on. It completely changes your question.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the advice. I'll edit it later today. It's a lot more code and more explaining but I'll try to keep it succinct. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is completely normal. Remember that a for loop calls repeatedly. So `for num in 0..<5` will make it run 4 times. At the first time, `num` is 0, so

```
for num in 0..<(count)){
        print(num)
}
```

prints nothing, and then immediately calls the completion handler, which prints "DONE". At the second time, `num` is 1, therefore the inner for loop will run 1 time and print 0, then print "DONE" so on so forth.

The desired output can be achieved by using

```
runThenPrint(5, completion: imDone)
```

as you just want the 'inner' for loop to be run 5 times.

Comment: I already knew I can get that using the inner loop by itself. Thanks anyway though